# Screen freezes when aura:iteration is running

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

I am using aura:iteration to dynamically render components and as the components are many, it is taking a bit of time. During this, I want to show spinner till all components are rendered, but as soon as the aura:iteration starts, screen freezes and we can't click anything, neither the spinner is shown. This  gives a very bad impression of the application as till that end user don't know why nothing is happening.By the time the iteration is complete, spinner is hidden by my code.

**markup:**

```
<aura:attribute name="valuesList" type="String" />
<!--some code-->
    <aura:iteration var="fieldName" items="{!v.valuesList}">
                   <td >
                        <div class="slds-truncate">
                           <span>
                              <c:NewComponent name="{!fieldName}"/>
                           </span>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
     </aura:iteration>
<!--some code-->
```

This table is already rendered and I reset the "valuesList" in my controller to some new list as:

**Controller:**

```
helper.showSpinner(component);    //function to show spinner
component.set('v.valuesList', someNewList);
helper.hideSpinner(component);   //function to hide spinner
```

This will make the aura iteration to re-trigger and new values are displayed. But the spinner never is displayed. What could be the reason? Also I find aura:iteration very annoying, is there any other way to implement things that aura:iteration?

Comment: Did you change to $A.createComponent dynamic components or the aura:iteration? Using the aura:iteration but takes more time as you said screen freezes. can you tell me the workaround for this problem or suggestions

Comment: I don't remember what I did that time as this was long time back :). After working 2 years on lightning components : I think you can use `aura:if` with truth condition that do not render `aura:iteration` till the list is not empty. And in `else` part, show spinner. This way when list is populated asynchronously after some time, condition is toggled and `aura:iteration` is rendered with pre-filled list. In this case no need to show hide spinner from Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do component.set, it sets asynchronously the component attribute, so showSpinner and hideSpinner are already called when your aura:iteration is starting after the rerender provoked by the update of v.valueList value.

If you are bored by aura:iteration, you can dynamically create components with a loop from JS controller.

Use $A.createComponents method then add all created components in a blank DIV element.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

If you do that, your showSpinner and hideSpinner methods will work if you call showSpinner before calling $A.createComponents, then call hideSpinner in $A.createComponents callback